# Overloading operator= issue

Tags: c++, overloading

I am writing c++ program.

This is snippet of main method:

```
 Student * array = new Student[4];

    int i = 0;

    for(char x = 'a'; x < 'e'; x++){        

       array[i] = new Student(x+" Bill Gates");
        i++;
    }
    defaultObject.addition(array, 4);
```

This line  `array[i] = new Student(x+" Bill Gates");` throws an error:

```
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Run.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Run.o Run.cpp
In file included from Run.cpp:12:
Assessment3.hpp:53:39: warning: no newline at end of file
Run.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
Run.cpp:68: error: no match for 'operator=' in '*((+(((unsigned int)i) * 8u)) + array) = (string(((+((unsigned int)x)) + ((const char*)" Bill Gates")), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const std::allocator<char>*)(&allocator<char>())))), (((Student*)operator new(8u)), (<anonymous>->Student::Student(<anonymous>), <anonymous>)))'
Student.hpp:19: note: candidates are: Student& Student::operator=(Student&)
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/g/Aristotelis/C++/assessment3'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/g/Aristotelis/C++/assessment3'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/Run.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

Student class is over here:

```
#include "Student.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Student::Student(){
    in = "hooray";
}

Student::Student(string in) {
    this -> in = in;
}

Student::Student(const Student& orig) {
}

Student::~Student() {
}
Student & Student::operator=(Student & student){
    if(this != &student){
        this->in = student.in;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Header file is here:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef STUDENT_HPP
#define STUDENT_HPP

class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(string in);
    Student(const Student& orig);
    virtual ~Student();
    Student & operator=(Student & student); // overloads = operator
private:
    string in;
};

#endif  /* STUDENT_HPP */
```

This part of program creates array of type Student and stores objects of type student. The the array is passed to compare the values according to bubble sort. What might be the problem?

Comment: Note that your expression `x+" Bill Gates"` doesn't do what you expect, either. It does *not* do string concatenation because neither argument is a string. Instead, it advances a pointer to the character array " Bill Gates" by as many positions as the code point of `x` (e.g. for `x=='a'` in ASCII, it goes to the 97th character of " Bill Gates", which obviously doesn't exist) and then interprets whatever it finds there as C string. If you are lucky, you get a segmentation fault (or your platform's equivalent). Otherwise you most likely just get garbage.

Comment: your array is not array of Student* it's array of Student. So `array[i] = *(new Student(x+" Bill Gates"));`

Comment: @Yappie: There is no way to `delete` the pointer returned by `new` in that statement. It would leak memory every time it's used.

Comment: Your assignment operator needs to either accept it's argument by const reference, or by value.  Not by non-const reference, otherwise, you can't do this: `array[i] = Student()`, because that's trying to bind a non-const reference to a temporary, which is illegal.

Comment: @Blastfurnace:  Thanks, It's really stupid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'array' is an array of students declared on the freestore not of array of pointers to students so you can't assign a pointer to them, new returns a pointer to a new location on the freestore. Instead you assign a student to the indexed location.

```
//no new, you are assigning to a memory block already on the 
array[i]=student("bob");
```

Also whilst I am here, you can't concatenate a C string and a char like that. You can however use a std::string to do that heavy lifting.

```
char x='a';
std::string bill("bill gates");
std::string temp=bill+x;
```

Finally, you will save a lot of time, if you a vector instead a C array, a vector will manage it's own memory and provides a interface for you to use.

```
std::vector<student> array(4, student("Bill Gates"));
```

Vectors and string are the defacto way of dealing with arrays and string in c++.

Comment: @ucas: And?  He said a lot more than that.

Comment: Now I get this error: Run.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
Run.cpp:70: error: expected primary-expression before "array"
Run.cpp:70: error: expected `;' before "array"

Comment: on the line before line 70, you are missing a semi colon or you have a n incomplete statement

Comment: It wants semicolon in this line: std::vector<student> array(4, student("Bill Gates")); before array keyword.

Comment: can't really say without seeing the code, you included #include <vector> but usually it is when the preceding statement is malformed.

Comment: array[i]= std::vector<Student> array(4, Student("Bill Gates")); I have included <vector>

Comment: init the vector like this `std::vector<Student> array(4);` 4 is the size. Then access an element with `array[0]` or whatever index you want. see this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/ and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 111111's answer...

The code `x+" Bill Gates"` is attempting to add a `char` to a `char[]`, which is undefined.  At least one of the operands to the + operator must already be a string.  You may want to consider using `x + string(" Bill Gates")`.

Comment: Actually, the operation is *not* undefined (however with the values given in the program, it indeed gives undefined behaviour, unless run on a platform with a very unusual character encoding). `x+"Bill Gates"` converts `x` to `int` and decays the array to a pointer to the first element, and therefore you have just normal pointer arithmetic. For example if `x` were `'\4'`, the `Student` object would get initialized with the string `"l Gates"`.